# Is there an SCSS parser that outputs an AST?

Tags: parsing, sass, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm wondering if there is a SCSS (or Sass) parser, preferably written in JavaScript, that will output an abstract syntax tree.

These are perfect examples of I'm looking for:

- [css-parse](https://github.com/visionmedia/css-parse)
- [mensch](https://github.com/brettstimmerman/mensch)

UPDATE: The reason I'm asking is that I want to build a tool that would enforce a particular style of coding for SCSS and I can't do that with the above as they re-indent the compiled CSS, move braces, etc.

Comment: What's wrong with sending the compiled CSS through those applications?

Comment: I updated my question to answer that.

Comment: What's wrong with css-parse?  It appears to be the perfect answer to your question.

Comment: @IraBaxter `css-parse` parses CSS, not Sass (that I know of).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found a tool that might help.

It's a CSS/preprocessor parser called [`gonzales-pe`](https://github.com/tonyganch/gonzales-pe).

I hope this helps anyone else looking at this.

Comment: Also see Sass Thematic, which builds upon Gonzales to parse and assemble a deeply-nested abstract syntax tree with resolved `@import` statements. https://github.com/gmac/sass-thematic

Comment: You could also take a look at https://github.com/salesforce-ux/scss-parser